# URL redirection: Server side redirection to a directory/folder in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, servlets, bit.ly

I'm implementing a URL shortener like bit.ly. For this, I have a Java servlet backend which does a `response.redirect(targetURL)` for every redirection request.

This works fine for HTTP requests, but I'm having a problem with `file://` protocols. The problematic case is this:

1. The target is a directory (such as `file:///N:/somefolder` where `N:` is a network drive)
2. The client browser is IE

For Firefox, this works fine, the directory listing is shown in the browser as if I'd typed '`file:///n:/somefolder`' in the address bar (and I have my server added to Firefox's list of trusted URIs)

For IE, if I type '`file:///n:/somefolder`' into a browser and hit Enter, it opens a NEW explorer window. This is the exact behavior I want when I do a server side redirection, but this simply doesn't work. I get the "IE Cannot open..." error.

Is this not possible? Or is there some setting akin to the Firefox preferences that add my server to a list of "trusted" URLs for the redirection to happen?

Note that if the target is a file, such as `'file:///n:/somefolder/test.doc'` this works fine, even in IE!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Redirection from remote to local resources should be restricted due to security reasons but not all browsers enforce this correctly.

See this bulletin for an example of the exploit,

https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/713878

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible due to security restrictions. If the server machine has access to those resources at `java.io` level as well, then you could just act as sort of proxy yourself. Just create a `Servlet` which gets an `InputStream` of it using `FileInputStream` and write it to the `OutputStream` of the `HttpServletResponse` along with a correct set of headers.

Here's how the `doGet()` of such a servlet would look like:

```
String filename = request.getPathInfo();
File file = new File("n:/somefolder", filename);

response.setContentType(getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName()));
response.setContentLength(file.length());

BufferedInputStream input = null;
BufferedOutputStream output = null;

try {
    input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
} finally {
    if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
    if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
}
```

Map this servlet on an `url-pattern` like `/files/*` and call it with `http://example.com/contextname/files/test.doc`. You can find [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html) another basic example.

Comment: I know I'm no hotshot in Servlets, so forgive me if this sounds silly : What you've given looks like a file servlet.

What I'm asking is - why is it possible to do a response.redirect("N:/somefolder/somefile.doc") BUT not response.redirect("N:/somefolder") - On Internet Explorer?

(Both work on Firefox)

I fail to see the correlation here...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't get any satisfactory answers to my question. I've found a workaround that works while redirecting to directories in IE: have your server send a link to the target, instead of an actual redirect. E.g. the server sends html of the form

```
<a href="file:///N:/somefolder">click here</a>
```

This would require an additional click from the user, but would work.